# Angular2 unable to map a single JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

How do you map and use a JSON reponse that is a single object, rather than an array?

Recently, I started adding a new feature to a project I'm working on that should be taking a JSON response from an API and filling out a simple template with data from it. Shouldn't be difficult, right? Well, no... and yet, yes...

**Mock version of the JSON response:**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Acaeris",
}
```

**profile.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Profile } from './profile';

/**
 * This class provides the Profile service with methods to read profile data
 */
@Injectable()
export class ProfileService {
    /**
     * Creates a new ProfileService with the injected Http.
     * @param {Http} http - The injected Http.
     * @constructor
     */
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    /**
     * Returns an Observable for the HTTP GET request for the JSON resource.
     * @return {Profile} The Observable for the HTTP request.
     */
    get(): Observable<Profile> {
        return this.http.get('assets/profile.json')
            .map(res => <Profile>res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    /**
     * Handle HTTP error
     */
    private handleError (error: any) {
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

**profile.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProfileService } from '../services/profile/profile.service';
import { Profile } from '../services/profile/profile';

/**
 * This class represents the lazy loaded ProfileComponent
 */
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'sd-profile',
    templateUrl: 'profile.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['profile.component.css'],
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

    errorMessage: string;
    profile: Profile;

    /**
     * Creates an instance of the ProfileComponent with the injected
     * ProfileService
     *
     * @param {ProfileService} profileService - The injected ProfileService
     */
    constructor(public profileService: ProfileService) {}

    /**
     * Get the profile data
     */
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getProfile();
    }

    /**
     * Handles the profileService observable
     */
    getProfile() {
        this.profileService.get()
            .subscribe(
                data => this.profile = data,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );
    }
}
```

**profile.ts**

```
export interface Profile {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

And I'm just trying to output it using `{{profile.name}}` but this ends up with the console showing a whole load of error messages and no output. If I try to check the contents of `profile` after it has loaded, it tells me it is `undefined`.

However, here's the confusing part. If I replace all the `Profile` references to `Profile[]`, wrap the JSON in an array, add `*ngFor="let p of profile"` abd use `{{p.name}}` everything works fine. Unfortunately, in the actual finished application I would not have control of the JSON format. So what am I doing wrong when trying to handle it as a single object in comparison to handling as an array of objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like at expression {{profile.name}} profile variable is undefined at page rendering moment. You can try either add some getter like this:

```
get profileName(): string { return this.profile ? this.profile.name ? ''; }
```

and use at template {{profileName}} or you can use ngIf at template like this:

```
<div *ngIf="profile">{{profile.name}}</div>
```

or shorter (as drewmoore suggested at comment below):

```
<div>{{profile?.name}}</div>
```

When you are working with array it is the same situation - at first rendering time array is undefined. ngFor handles this for you and renders nothing. When async operation of getting 'profile items' is complete - UI is rerendered again with correct values.

Comment: Correct diagnosis, but FYI: [the Elvis operator](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/elvis-operator-in-angular-2.0) exists as syntax sugar for precisely this:  `<div>{{profile?.name}}</div>`

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. It's undefined at render time if an object but defined if an array of objects? The problem is that I'm having to have the JSON as `[{ "id": 1, "name": "Acaeris"}]` instead of as it is supplied `{ "id", "name": "Acaeris"}` and therefore treat it as an array of objects for it to not throw an error.

Comment: Array is undefined too, but ngFor handles this case and renders nothing at first. After array is populated - UI rerendered

Comment: A small correction, the question mark syntax is called [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html) within the Angular 2 template context.

Comment: Thank you very much that makes sense now.

Answer (score -1):

The `map`function returns Observables which are a collection of elements. It basically work the same way as the `map` function for arrays.

Now to solve you can replace the `Profile` references by `Profile[]` and use `{{profile[0].name}}`.

Comment: Tried that, just keep getting the same error I get before wrapping the JSON:`EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: comp.profile is undefined
View_ProfileComponent_0@/ProfileModule/ProfileComponent/component.ngfactory.js:45:5 [angular]
 

this._console.error('EXCEPTION: ' + this._extractMessage(error));`

Comment: 'map' function returns Observable, not array of Observables. Take a look at documentation: https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35#map.

Comment: What I ment was Observables are collections of elements. I' phrased my answer poorly sorry for that.

Comment: Observable is not collection of elements. The Observable object represents the object that sends notifications. Observer is subscribed to this notifications. You are doing this when call subscribe method.